# Transfer Bitcoins from Coinbase to an Offline Wallet

Tags: coinbase.com, paper-wallet, sending

Besides using the `send bitcoins` option, is there a way I can transfer my `bitcoins` from my online Coinbase account to an offline wallet? I mainly want to do this because I'd recently found out that Bitcoin is located in the US and can be seized by the Obama Regime at any time.

Edit: I guess what I'm trying to ask here is: is it possible to export an Online Wallet Private Key and import it on an Offline Wallet? If so, how?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, coinbase allows you to create a paper wallet.

http://blog.coinbase.com/post/51573799308/use-coinbase-to-export-your-bitcoins-to-a-paper-wallet

Comment: Is there a way I can export my Coinbase online private key and import it in an offline wallet though?

Comment: No. You will need to create a paper wallet and send your bitcoin to that new address.

Comment: so it's basically transferring bitcoins then, meaning you'll have to pay a fee for every transfer

Answer (score 0):

Do not use coinbase to create the offline wallet. Instead, use an offline tool or an hardware wallet, take note of the public address and send the bitcoins to that address

Comment: Gianluca - What offline tool or hardware wallet would you suggest then and how do you do this? Withdraw all crypto and then re-establish at new location?

Comment: I would suggest an hardware wallet like Trezor or Ledger. A paper wallet would be ok (https://www.bitaddress.org) but make sure to run it when you are offline!