# Transfer bitcoins from Coinbase account to an offline Script/Paper

Tags: coinbase.com, paper-wallet

How would I go about transferring some of my bitcoins from my Coinbase account to a physical paper script or paper form? Also, am I limited as to how many bitcoins I can transfer to one set of keys "public/private"? Are there paper bills already made to where there is a public key as to where the private key are covered and are they considered safe? I know I asked quite a bit and do appreciate any and all information available.

Comment: related: [Transfer Bitcoins from Coinbase to an Offline Wallet](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/17548/5406), [How to save bitcoins as paper?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/1080/5406)

Answer (score 1):

Ok. You've asked multiple questions, so I'll split my answer up.

**How to transfer from Coinbase to Paper Wallet**

If your paper wallet is made by a good quality generator, it should have a private key, a public address and a qr code printed on it. You can scan the QR code with coinbase's send function, or if you don't have a camera, you can type the public address in by hand.

**Is there a max/minimum amount I can send to a Paper Wallet?**

Nope. Think of your paper wallet simply as an access key. To actually use it, you need a wallet client to use the private key. It's the same as any other wallet.

**Pre-made paper wallets that come with something covering the public key?**

There are some specially made ones that you can buy with tamper-proof stickers, however these are made more for a visual appeal than actual use and you really don't need them. Fold your private key unwards, so that the private key can't simply be glanced at. Then put it somewhere safe where only you know it's whereabouts.